# Ionic 4: Ionic Tab Bar isn't displayed in Chrome

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to make Website with a Tab-Bar at the top. It all seems to work in Firefox and Edge, but in Chrome it doesn't show the tab-bar at all. My home.page.html looks like this:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="top">

    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Am besten bewertet</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Trends</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="ice-cream"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="new">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Neueste</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-header>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer realised previous answer blocked other elements on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ion-tab-bar has `display: flex;` and `height:100%` in its styles which causes it not to render in chrome for whatever reason but you can get round it by adding `style="display: contents;"` to the ion-tab-bar element and it will displayed properly.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-tabs style="display: contents;">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="top">

    <ion-tab-button tab="home">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Am besten bewertet</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-badge>6</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Trends</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="ice-cream"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="new">
      <ion-router-outlet name="one"></ion-router-outlet>
      <ion-label>Neueste</ion-label>
      <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-header>
```